# How to stop text in tkinter from appearing blurry/pixelated?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

[image: My tk window.]

This happens a lot of the time and really makes ui look ugly. Is there a way to fix this? maybe condense it less?

Answer (score 4):

Setting your DPI awareness to 1 should resolve your issue

```
from ctypes import windll
windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1)
```

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal example to show to use it? Also it might be worth adding [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellscalingapi/nf-shellscalingapi-setprocessdpiawareness) link to your answer.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I have tried this and it makes very minimal (if any) difference.

Answer (score 0):

*This happens a lot of the time and really makes ui look ugly.*

According to [wiki.tcl-lang.org](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Alternative+Canvases)

> The Tk canvas lacks modern features such as antialiasing, and an alpha
> channel for transparency/translucency.

which is probably cause of your elements being jagged. There are alternatives listed, but my understanding is that they are made fot `tcl` language, not `python`.